# iOS Universal App Layout Issue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

[image][image][image]Please see the attached screenshots of the app running - as you can see there is an area at the bottom of the iPhone screen that is not used. The same area of the iPad detail is however. I know there must a bar somewhere I need to hide but I can't find anything amiss.

I have a UITabBar controller as my root VC, which has a tab that leads to the UISplitViewController. As far as I am aware, the UISplitViewController is being used in the standard form.

Can anybody point me in the right direction. I am not sure what information to post, so please ask if you need more info.

Comment: The gap looks about the size of a tab bar so check your simulated metrics on your Detail view controller and make sure it isn't simulating a tab bar.

Comment: I just checked that - set the simulated metrics for bottom bar to none for the navigationviewcontroller(s) too... still doing the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. In the end though, the solution was fairly simple! I checked the Extend Edges Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars options for the UISplitViewController and voila![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bvhL.png)

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

open storyboard

select ur viewcontroller

change wAny hAny

preview ur viewcontroller in iPad/iPhone and all devices u needed

and rotate ur preview screen.

Answer (score 0):

your How to solve this?

1. Review [Debugging Tricks and Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html) section of the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)
2. Compare storyboard with actual results - does your storyboard contain the same issue (most lightly not).
3. Review the constraints you have set for the view in question.
4. Check your constraints for the [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) in view controller with the view in question.
5. Add an IBOutlet and instance variable for the bottom constraint of the view in question and set breakpoints. Implement any/all of the methods in the [UIContentContainer protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/sizeForChildContentContainer:withParentContainerSize:) to see what is happening with the constraint and the current class size.

6.Implement [- viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) to see any frame changes.